# Getting a table row of specified width to keep everything on one line and truncate one cell as needed? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

I have a basic table with four columns (let's call them A, B, C, D) and a specific desired width, 600px.  The contents are all text.  What I want is for the column widths to be allocated as follows:

- Columns A-C are just wide enough to fit the text without any wrapping, no wider
- Column D gets whatever width is left over, and cuts off any overflow instead of wrapping to a new line.

How can I accomplish this with CSS?

This is the closest I've gotten:

```
    <table style="width: 600px; table-layout: fixed;">
        <thead>
            <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Column A</th>
            <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Column B</th>
            <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Column C</th>
            <th>Column D</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">12345</td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Some Text</td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap;">Some More Text</td>
                <td style="white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">                        
                        Some very long text goes here.  This text is going to get cut off.  It won't all fit in this cell.  I hope it doesn't wrap onto a second line.  That would be bad.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In this case the width for Columns A, B, and C has nothing to do with the content.  It gives the cells too much space for short text and too little space for long text.  It does, however, properly truncate Column D.

I also tried setting the widths of Columns A-C to 1% and Column D to 100%, but then they all run together at the left edge of the table.

Any ideas how I can get that width calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Might you want some thing like this http://jsfiddle.net/2qHY3/3/ ..?

by removing

```
white-space: nowrap;text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

from the last `<td>`

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.  It results in displaying all the text in the last cell on multiple lines.  It also allocates the four columns equally instead of based on the content.

Comment: @NChase Do you want last column full text in one line..?